# Getting object assignment error when attempting to create a dictionary (Robot Framework)

Tags: dictionary, robotframework

I am attempting to create a dictionary based upon data in an xls spreadsheet. Below is my code. However, when performing the "set to dictionary" (last line of the code snippet below), I'm getting the following error: TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment. Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ExcelLibrary
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
${PageSheetName} =  Welcome Page
${WelcomeDict} =  Create Dictionary

*** Test Cases ***
Excel Sandbox Test
    Get Values from Spreadsheet
    #Print out the Dictionary

*** Keywords ***
Get Values from Spreadsheet
   # Open the file
   Open Excel Current Directory  ${Excel_File_Path}DataExtract.xls
   # Get the number of rows
   ${iTotalRows} =  Get Row Count  ${PageSheetName}
   # Loop through each row to get the data. Only need data from Columns A & B
   : FOR  ${iRowNum}  IN RANGE  1  ${iTotalRows}+1
   \  ${KeyVal} =  Read Cell Data By Name  ${PageSheetName}  A${iRowNum}
   \  ${Value} =  Read Cell Data By Name  ${PageSheetName}  B${iRowNum}
   \  Create the Welcome Page Dictionary  ${KeyVal}  ${Value}

Create the Welcome Page Dictionary
    [Arguments]  ${key}  ${val}
    Set To Dictionary  ${WelcomeDict}  ${key}  ${val}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this block of code:

```
*** Variables ***
${WelcomeDict} =  Create Dictionary
```

It is creating a string variable with the value "Create Dictionary". You cannot call keywords in the `*** Variables ***` section.

From the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-table):

> Variable tables are convenient, because they allow creating variables in the same place as the rest of the test data, and the needed syntax is very simple. **Their main disadvantages are that values are always strings and they cannot be created dynamically**.

If you want to initialize a dictionary, use `&`, and just don't provide any values:

```
*** Variables ***
&{WelcomeDict}=
```